# How can I conditionally include two differently named libraries of the same version for a cross-compile project in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, mingw, static-libraries

I have an Eclipse project that I want to compile on both Ubuntu and Windows.

I am using boost libraries (specifically asio) which require including the libboost_system...* library. I have compiled boost on both Windows and Ubuntu and ended up with `libboost_system_mgw48-mt-1_55.a` on Windows and `libboost_system.a`, `libboost_system.so`, `libboost_system.so.1.55.0` on Ubuntu.

I'm not sure which Ubuntu library I need to include but the bigger issue is how to include both the Windows and Ubuntu library but only on the right OS.

I am using the MinGW toolchain on Windows which by my understanding is more or less GCC? I am then assuming that I should simply use GCC on Ubuntu to have the same compile process.

Windows boost build commands:

```
bootstrap.bat mingw
b2 toolset=gcc
```

Ubuntu boost build commands:

```
bootstrap.sh
b2
```

Can Eclipse get the OS in use on a per install basis that I can access via a globally recognizable variable?

How can I then, assuming yes, use that information to conditionally include only the right libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to use two configurations: Debug-Win32 and Debug-Unix in the project properties. This keeps track of independent library & path configurations as well as different tool chains while still pulling from the same code base.